# Oracle connection string: difference between True and true in app.config file

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, app-config, case-sensitive

I use connection string to connect to Oracle DB by save it in config file.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringDB" connectionString="Data Source=TestDB;User ID=TUSER;Password=XXXX;Validate Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

the config work on some machine but some machine Error

'validate connection' cannot be set to an invalid value of 'True'

I need to change to

```
<add name="ConnectionStringDB" connectionString="Data Source=TestDB;User ID=TUSER;Password=XXXX;Validate Connection=true;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

Change from Validate Connection=True; to Validate Connection=true;

What diffrent for True and true and can I config machines to use True.
My C# windows application target framework is 3.5 connect to Oracle 10.2g

Add note:All machine is runing windows 7 x64

Comment: First thought is a Locale thing, but my gut tells me its a x86 vs x64 issue

Comment: It is on  windows 7 x64 machine.

Comment: Are they all the same SOE? Were the any config changes? Are all machines set to the same the locale? I would go lower case by default or use TNS. Weird issue.

Comment: They are same SOE and connect to same DB. I compare config file it change only True and true. but true is work for all machine.